# sql error on key word "references"

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'd like you guy to help me please. Here's some SQL code I'm trying to execute.

```
create table Personne (
id_personne serial primary key, 
nom text not null, 
prenom text not null, 
email text not null);

create table Ressource (
id_ressource serial primary key, 
nom_r text not null, 
url text not null,  
id_personne int not null, foreign key references Personne(id_personne));
```

I get an error like "syntax error nearby 'references Personne(id_personne))' line 5.

I don't know where it's from. I went to W3school.com and from what I understand, what I wrote is correct. But it just doesn't work.

Any kind of help would be appreciated !

PS : I tried on MySql and Postgresql, same result.

Comment: please tag the specific database , mysql or postgres

Comment: I tried on postgresql and mysql, same result.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the column name

```
create table Ressource (
id_ressource serial primary key, 
nom_r text not null, 
url text not null,  
id_personne int not null, 
foreign key(id_personne) references Personne(primary_key_from_personne));
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
            (you missed it)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. thanks for the helping hand. I'm really new to SQL language.

Comment: good luck with your learning , would you mind upvoting and accepting answer, it will help other to know that it really helped you